# Incrementing/Decrementing $a++ and ++$a. Can someone help me explain this?

Tags: php

I have one variable:

```
$a = 5;
```

Let's do the math below:

```
$a++ + $a- + -$a + ++$a + $a++ + ++$a - $a- + $a
```

With the help of the PHP language, I calculated **the result** as **22**. **But** I don't know **why** it got **this result**?
**Hope for a help!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Points to consider

- **$a++** : First $a value will be used in expression and then incremented.

```
$a = 5;
echo $a++;  // Will print 5 only, as $a is used first and then incremented.
echo $a;    // will print 6 as it is incremented in previous expression.
```

- **++$a** : First value is incremented and then incremented value of $a will be used in expressions.

```
$a = 5;
echo ++$a;  // Will print 6 as value is incremented first and then used in expression.
```

- **-$a** : simple negation of any value

```
$a = 5; $b = -6;

echo -$a;  // -5
echo -$b;  // 6
```

- Last but not least, **$a-**, it is `-(minus)` operator after `$a`, you can add space after it. But things turn out when another operator plus or minus is used b/w operands i.e. `$a- + $b`, you can say it does the operator multiplication.

```
-(minus) -(minus) ==> +(plus)
-(minus) +(plus)  ==> -(minus)
+(plus) -(minus)  ==> -(minus)
+(plus) +(plus)   ==> +(plus)

e.g.
$a = 5 ; $b = 10;

echo $a - - $b;  // $a + $b = 15
echo $a - + $b;  // $a - $b = -5
echo $a + - $b;  // $a - $b = -5
echo $a + + $b;  // $a + $b = 15
```

Now coming to your question

```
$a++ + $a- + -$a + ++$a + $a++ + ++$a - $a- + $a; 
==> simplify it with operator multiplication

($a++)   + $a - (-$a) + (++$a)   + ($a++)    + (++$a)   - $a - $a;
 5       + 6  - (-6)  + (7)      +  7        +  9       - 9  - 9;  // 22
(post +1)               (pre +1)   (post +1)   (pre +1)
```

Comment: @PhạmVănHậu Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

Basically, `$a++` increments the number after it has been used in the expression, and `++$a` increments it before it is used in the expression. Now PHP breaks down your long expressin into multiple individual smaller ones, so it is not totally transparent what is happening here.

PHP then evaluates from the left to the right. The single `-` and `+` combinations do not really make sense and are just interpreted as a `-` since you are telling PHP to subtract a positive number with the plus sign (`-+`) or to add a negative number with the minus sign (`+-`).

Therefore your expression evaluates step by step to:

```php
$a = 5;
var_dump($a++); // still 5 because it is only incremented afterwards
$a = 5;
var_dump($a++ + $a); // 11 since $a++ gets evaluated and then $a is added
$a = 5;
var_dump($a++ + $a- + -$a); // 17, removing a negative 6 => is the same as adding 6
$a = 5;
var_dump($a++ + $a- + -$a + ++$a); // 24 adding another 7 (pre-increment)
$a = 5;
var_dump($a++ + $a- + -$a + ++$a + $a++); // 31 adding another 7 (not increased from previous because of post-increment)
$a = 5;
var_dump($a++ + $a- + -$a + ++$a + $a++ + ++$a); // 40 adding another 9 because now both the post increment of the previous statement and the pre-increment of this one count
$a = 5;
var_dump($a++ + $a- + -$a + ++$a + $a++ + ++$a - $a); // 31 because removing 9 again
$a = 5;
var_dump($a++ + $a- + -$a + ++$a + $a++ + ++$a - $a- + $a); // 22 "adding" another negative 9, which removes 9 as before
```

Side note: While this might be fun as a exercise to understand what is going on, I would never recommend to use such long and complicated expressions where you do both use the value *and* change it at the same time. Your code would very quickly become un-understandable as proven by your example.